# Invoking Remote Systems LPEX Editor using java

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rpgle, rdi-plugin

We have a set of plugins installed in RDI where they display a list of native RPGLE programs and have got a set of classes that invoke the LPEX editor to allow editing the source file in the traditional Library/SoureFile/Member settings.
I now want to extend this to be able to add/edit RPGLE source in the IFS but cannot find the IBM classes that allow this. 
For the normal native source the code is

```
IQSYSMember memberObj;
IBMiConnection iSeriesConnection = RSEConnectionFactory.getISeriesConnection(connection);
memberObj = iSeriesConnection.getMember(
                        a.getSourceLibrary(), 
                        a.getSourceFile(), 
                        a.getSourceMember(), 
                        null);
QSYSEditableRemoteSourceFileMember editableMember = new QSYSEditableRemoteSourceFileMember(memberObj);
editableMember.open(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), false);
```

Obviously for source that are in IFS, all I have is a path (/home/path/QRPGLESRC/nnn.RPGLE).
I know I can go to Remote System Explorer and right hand click and select "Open with Remote Systems LPEX Editor" but need to do this from my plugins.
Anyone know which IBM classes allow this to happen?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [open(boolean,progressmonitor)](https://javadoc.midrange.com/rd/76/com/ibm/etools/iseries/rse/ui/resources/QSYSEditableRemoteSourceFileMember.html#open(boolean,%20IProgressMonitor)) method on `QSYSEditableRemoteSourceFileMember`

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed my issue:

```
FileServiceSubSystem fileService = LpexHelper.getFileServiceSubsystem(iSeriesConnection);
IRemoteFile remoteFile = fileService.getRemoteFileObject(path, new NullProgressMonitor());
    SystemEditableRemoteFile file = new SystemEditableRemoteFile(remoteFile);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.open(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), true);
    }
```